# Template metaprogramming to avoid cast

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Consider the following code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
enum class Type { D1, D2 };

struct Base { 
 virtual ~Base() = default;
 virtual void doSth() = 0;
 virtual Type getType() = 0; 
};

struct D1 : Base { 
 Type getType() override { return Type::D1; } 
 void doSth() override { }
};

struct BaseExt : Base {
    virtual void doSth2() = 0;
};

struct D2 : BaseExt { 
 Type getType() override { return Type::D2; }
 void doSth() override { }
 void doSth2() override {}  
};

template <typename... Deriveds>
struct Manager
{
    Manager(Deriveds... ds) {
        _t = tuple<Deriveds...>(ds...); 
       // MAGIC NEEDED HERE TO POPULATE _mapOfTypes
    } 

    void go(Type /* t */) {
        // MAGIC NEEDED HERE
        //std::get<_mapOfTypes[t]>(_t)->doSth();
    }

    void go2()
    {
       // std::get<_mapOfTypes[Type::D2]>(_t)->doSthD2(); // THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
    }

    tuple<Deriveds...> _t;
    map<Type, int> _mapOfTypes;
};

int main()
{
   D1 d1;
   D2 d2;
   Manager<D1,D2> m(d1,d2);
   m.go(Type::D1);
   m.go2();
}
```

Link to this code:
**https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jr5HJWimrL1wvZbs**

I know that I can store pointers to Base in the Manager, that's simple, oldschool. But in the case when I need to call a method from BaseExt (in go2 method), I would have to make a static_cast from Base* to BaseExt*.

I am thinking if it is possible to do it differently with template metaprogramming. I would like to call the method doSth2 without any cast. Since I have a tuple of concrete types implementing Base or Base2 and I know in the compile time which object is in which place in the tuple, I would like to make a call to this object without using the Base or Base2 interface.

I tried implementing this but I got stuck. I know that I can store parameter_pack in a tuple and later operate on this tuple using index_sequence. However I have a problem with populating the _mapOfTypes. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You should test your example code before posting, it has quite a few typos. An online compiler such as [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) is a very useful tool for that.

Comment: You are right, I was too quick. I have updated the code and provided working link to online compiler (Wandbox.org).

Comment: You could populate such a map, but it won't help at all, since a `std::map` stores data at run time, but template arguments like the `N` in `std::get<N>(tup)` must be determined at compile time.  The overall results you want are probably possible, but can you write it out exactly?  For example, "If `Deriveds` contains exactly one class which inherits `BaseExt`...".  Be sure to consider what should happen if you have multiple or no template arguments of a given base: cause a compile error? use the first? do nothing when called?

Comment: Why can't map be populated at compile time? Tuple can be, why can't map? In case of the problem with more than one Derived from BaseExt being used I think it could be a reasonable approach to use the first one. Or reject such usage.

Comment: @YotKay Because it's a structure created for the run time, not compile time :o

Comment: Why then can tuple be populated both in runtime and compile time?

Comment: Could Boost::Hana::map be used here? Anyone has experience with Hana and may say something here?